# Correct proof for divisibilty question

Tags: proof-verification, gcd-and-lcm

So I had an exam where one of the questions was:
Let a and b be two integers with 1 as their greatest common divisor and let c be a third integer. Show that if a|bc then a|c.

My argument was: 
"That gcd (a,b)=1 means that a and b have no common factors except 1.That an integer a divides another c implies that a is a factor to c. Since a|bc, a is a factor to bc. Because a can not be a factor to b, a does not divide b. a then has to be a factor to c which means that a divides c."

Summarized:
a is a factor to bc.
no factor to a except number 1 is a factor to b .
a is not a factor to b.
a must then be a factor to c.

My teacher said that this is wrong and I have discussed it a bit with him but still cant understand his argument. He gave the exemple  6|12 but 6 does not divide 4 and 6 does not divide 3. He also says this proves my argument is wrong even though the numbers in his exemple do not fulfill that a and b should have 1 as their greatest common divisor. This is what still confuses med.  If it says to let a and b have 1 as their greatest common divisor, then why cant I argue from the standpoint that they do? Maybe i was not clear enough or do not understand the exact logic in making correct proofs.

(I know there are better proofs for this question such as from auc+bvc=c but this is all I could figure by then.I also found that I would probably have needed to mention the special case a=b=1 where a actually divides b)

Comment: You argued (I quote) "In order for an integer to divide another it has to be a factor to that other integer.Therefore since a does not divide b and a divides bc then a divides c." Nothing in that argument uses that $\gcd(a,b)=1$.  The only reason you give that $a|c$ is because $a\not \mid b$ and $a \mid bc$. He gave a counter example.  $a = 6$; $b=4; c =3$. He did not use $\gcd(a,b) =1$ because *YOU* did not use $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ You only used $\gcd(a,b)=1$ to get to $a\not \mid b$  But that isn't they *only* way $a\not \mid b$ and if you *dont* use $\gcd(a,b)=1$ as a reason, he doesnt either.

Comment: Yes I can finnaly see it, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For the proof: Hint: write $ax+by=1$ for some integers $x$ and $y$.  Then, multiply by $c$.

If $a$ were prime, then your argument would work.  The problem is that *part* of $a$ might divide $b$ and another *part* would divide $c$.

If your argument were true, then it would prove that "if $a\nmid b$ and $a\mid bc$, then $a\mid c$", which is false.  You never use the full power of the gcd in your argument only that for $a\not=\pm1$, $a$ does not divide $b$.

Comment: But if and b signify only integers that have gcd (1) then part of a cant divide b, right? I think the problem is i thought it would be enough to state that a and b have gcd (1) and then that would always apply to a and b when i hade them in my arguments..

Comment: You are right that if $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime then no part of $a$ can divide $b$.  You can make such an argument work, but it is more delicate than your proof.  One of the difficulties is that if $a=4$, then you could prove that the prime $2$ divides $c$, but do you know that $2$ divides $c$ twice?  It becomes a notational nightmare (and uses many theorems that you might not have covered yet) to get it to all work out.

Comment: Yes what helped med understand is what you said that a can divide part of b and part of c. Thanks

Comment: Lets say my argument was as follows: a does not divide b and ADDITIONALLY NO PART OF A DIVIDES B, therefore since a|bc then a must also divide c. So that stil not sufficient then, is that what youre saying?

Comment: Yes, that is not sufficient.  There is a large jump from that no part of $a$ divides $b$ to $a$ dividing $c$.  You haven't connected the statements to $c$ nor shown that the product of the parts of $a$ divide $c$ (even though the individual parts divide $c$).

Comment: The argument and connection to c would be that a is a factor to bc but none of a is a factor to b. If none of a was a factor to b and a was not a factor to c it could not be a factor to bc. In other words all the factors of a are also in bc but none of then are in b, so all of them must be in c. Therefore a|c since any factor is also a divisor.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about why your teacher's example proves that your argument is invalid, note that a crucial part of your argument relied on the statement

> In order for an integer to divide another it has to be a factor to that other integer. Therefore since $a$ does not divide $b$ and $a$ divides $bc$ then $a$ divides $c$.

You are claiming here that this statement is true for *any* integers $a,b,$ and $c$ as long as $a$ does not divide $b$. Therefore, if one can find a counterexample using *any* integers $a,b,$ and, $c$ such that $a$ does not divide $b$ then your argument would be invalidated. Your teacher has given you such a counterexample. It is true that $6$, $3$, and $4$ are integers such that $6$ does not divide $3$ (or $4$) but $6\mid 3\cdot4$. The $\gcd(a,b)$ in the counterexample is irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry, It is not so clear to me. He is claiming that this statement is true for any integers a,b with gcd(a,b)=1. Please can you explain better this point?. Thanks

Comment: @gimusi The OP never really uses that the gcd is 1, only the weaker condition that $a$ doesn't divide $b$.

Comment: @gimusi Yes the OP is claiming that the statement it is true when $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ but provides incorrect justification as to why. The justification the OP gives is that for "an integer" to divide "another [integer]" then . . . [insert rest of the statement]. By saying this the OP is trying to justify the fact that this is true in the specific case of $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ by claiming that it is true for any old integers, which is incorrect. As Michael Burr states, the OP never actually uses that $\gcd(a,b) = 1$.

Comment: Ok I see..  So if I clarified "if a and b signify any integers such that they have gcd (1) then a|c if a|bc" that still would not make any difference? I suppose that is what is argued for in first answers above.

Comment: @Lukas That is a correct statement, but it is exactly what you are trying to prove, so you need to find an argument that proves it. As your teacher's example shows, and as I elaborated on in my answer, your original argument did not provide correct justification.

Comment: Thus the following statement is not true?: "Let a and b be two integers with 1 as their greatest common divisor and let c be a third integer: if a|bc then a|c". Can you give an example please? Thanks

Comment: @gimusi I thought I was claiming tha. Since the question says let a and b have gcd (1) and I repeated that in the beginning of my arguments I didnt think a and b in my statements would all of a sudden be interpreted as any integers.

Comment: @gimusi No, that statement is true, but that is exactly what needs to be proved. One cannot just state it as fact and call it proved.

Comment: @wgrenard sorry it should have been "if a and b signify any integers such thay they have gcd (1) then a does not divide b and therefore a|c if a|bc." My proof is based on a can not divide b if gcd (a,b)=1. Maybe I just need more time to consider what You all have already explained

Comment: @wgrenard but the statement can be easily proved by FTA, that’s maybe was the ideas of Lukas. Would be this a correct way to proceed for a proof?

Comment: @Lukas I apologize, I did skip part of the argument because I initially misread your statement. See my edit. Essentially, nothing has changed, I just added a bit.

Comment: Ok, so the thing is that i didnt think i was claiming it holds true for ANY integers, like both you and my teacher say I do. I thought it would be enough to begin by saying gcd (a,b)=1 and then a and b in my argument would not be interpreted as ANY integers.

Comment: @Lukas from my point of you your argument was very clear in the hypothesis that gcd(a,b)=1. I really don’t understand at the moment all the discussion. However I will read later all the thread in order to clarify better the concept. Thank you all guys! It was a pleasure can be here to discuss math with you.

Comment: @Lukas Though you begin by stating that $(a,b) = 1$ you never used it. You only use that $a \nmid b$. So essentially you are arguing that the statement you make holds for any integers $a,b,$ and $c$ where $a\nmid b$. Which is false. What I think you are trying to say is that now you know it is false, but it is true if $(a,b) = 1$. Yes, it is true in that case, but simply adding that $(a,b) = 1$ to the beginning of the proof doesn't provide justification that it is true. You are simply stating, "If I add the condition $(a,b) = 1$ then it works." But *why*? That is what you are trying to prove.

Comment: Thanks alot all of you, I finally get it... that a does not divide b simply does not prove that a|c if a|bc. I was so sure about that part so I didnt realise that was the missing link.

Comment: I edited my answer to make it more exactly the way it was. I think maybe it could be argued that my conclusion is att least more accurate if the first statement " a and b have no common factors" could be considered part of the final argument.

Comment: Part of my argument was that a and b have no common factors. What the teacher says by his counterexample is basically that "a can be a number that has one commom factor with b and one in c". But how can he erase my argument

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I were asked to prove:

If $M$ is even than $M = N + 1$ for some odd number.

And I gave the proof:  Since $M$ is even then $M \ge 2$.  So $M > 1$ so $M = N + 1$ for some odd number.

And you wanted to show my proof was wrong with a counter-example.  $7 \ge 2$ so $7 > 1$ but if $7 = N + 1$ then $N = 6$ and $N$ is not odd.

And I said "But $7$ isn't even.  Your premise was that $M$ is even."

We'll, I'd have a slight point.  $M$ is even *was* my premise.  But the problem with my argument is I didn't *use* the premise.  I used the premise to get to a point *that I could have gotten to without the premise*.  And then in giving my argument, I gave an argument that didn't *need* the premise, and which was false.

It is true that if $M$ is even than $M \ge 2$ but there are other numbers with that property.  And then I tried to argue that because $M \ge 2$ and *NOT* because $M$ is even, that it is because $M\ge 2$ that $M = N+1; N$ odd.

That is *NOT* why $M= N+1; N$ odd. And a counter example for some other $M\ge 2$ (but in this case $M$ not even) shows that my argument *why* was wrong.

So same with your proof.  You argued that because $\gcd(a,b) =1$ then $a\not \mid b$.  Fine, but that's not the *only* way to get $a\not \mid b$.  You can get $a\not \mid b$ by simply taking $a = 6; b= 4$.

Then you argued *BECAUSE* $a\not \mid b$ and $a|bc$ that it must follow that $a|c$.  Well, that is *not* the reason.  And $6 \not \mid 4$ and $6|3*4$ but $6\not \mid 3$ shows that that can not be the reason.

You can't claim that this counter-example is faulty because $\gcd(4,6)\ne 1$ unless you can give an argument that that was relevant.   Because your argument did not use $\gcd(a,b)= 1$ in any necessary way, this is a valid counter-argument.  However if you *had* used $\gcd(a,b) =1$ is a necessary way, this would not be a valid counter-argument and indeed, I'd be incapable of giving a valid counter-argument as there would be none.

....

Or suppose I offered a proof that cows were rabbits.  My proof:  Rabbits eat lettuce.  ANd cows eat lettuce.  Therefore cow are rabbits.

And you tried to show me a counter-argument, "Goats aren't rabbits and goats eat lettuce."

And I said "But goats aren't cows so that doesn't satisfy my basic premise that I'm talking about animals that are cows."

Comment: Thanks allt for this thorough explanation. Do you think it would make any difference if I had clarified my argument like this (which is what I was thinking but not really saying): Since a and b have no common factors except 1 and no other part (than 1) of a divides b and a does not divide b, therefore a|c given that a|bc. In other words the reson is not simply a does not divide b but also that no part of a divides b..

Comment: That is the correct idea.  Formally, I'd like to see that a little fleshed out or formally defined, but yes, that is the correct idea and key factor.

Comment: Ok cool! Well my full argument was actually: a|bc, a and b have no common factors except 1, a does not divide b, for all these reasons a|c.